# Why am I getting memory leaks in SimplePie when using $item->get_permalink()?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, simplepie

I'm using [SimplePie](http://www.simplepie.org) with PHP 5.3 (with gc enabled) to parse my RSS feeds. This works well and without problems when doing something like the following:

```
$simplePie = new SimplePie();
$simplePie->set_feed_url($rssURL);
$simplePie->enable_cache(false);
$simplePie->set_max_checked_feeds(10);
$simplePie->set_item_limit(0);
$simplePie->init();
$simplePie->handle_content_type();

foreach ($simplePie->get_items() as $key => $item) {
    $item->get_date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $item->get_id();
    $item->get_title();
    $item->get_content();
    $item->get_description();
    $item->get_category();
}
```

Memory debugging over 100 iterations (with **different** RSS feeds):

[image: SimplePie without using get_permalink()]

But when using `$item->get_permalink()`, my memory debugging looks like this over 100 iterations  (with **different** RSS feeds).

**Code to produce problem**:

```
foreach ($simplePie->get_items() as $key => $item) {
    $item->get_date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $item->get_id();
    $item->get_title();
    $item->get_permalink(); //This creates a memory leak
    $item->get_content();
    $item->get_description();
    $item->get_category();
}
```

[image: SimplePie get_permalink memory leak]

**Things I've tried**:

- Using `get_link` instead of `get_permalink`
- Using `__destroy` as mentioned [here](http://simplepie.org/wiki/faq/i_m_getting_memory_leaks) (even though it should be fixed for 5.3)

**Current debugging process**:

I seem to have traced the problem down to `SimplePie_Item::get_permalink` -> `SimplePie_Item::get_link` -> `SimplePie_Item::get_links` -> `SimplePie_Item::sanitize` -> `SimplePie::sanitize` -> `SimplePie_Sanitize::sanitize` -> `SimplePie_Registry::call` -> `SimplePie_IRI::absolutize` as of now.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This is actually not a memory leak, but rather static function caches that aren't being cleaned!**

This is due to `SimplePie_IRI::set_iri` (and `set_authority`, and `set_path`). They set a static `$cache` variable, but they don't unset or clean this when a new instance of `SimplePie` is created, which means the variables only gets bigger and bigger.

This can be fixed by changing

```
public function set_authority($authority)
{
    static $cache;

    if (!$cache)
        $cache = array();

    /* etc */
```

to

```
public function set_authority($authority, $clear_cache = false)
{
    static $cache;
    if ($clear_cache) {
        $cache = null;
        return;
    }

    if (!$cache)
        $cache = array();

    /* etc */
```

..etc in the following functions:

- `set_iri`,
- `set_authority`,
- `set_path`,

And adding a destructor to `SimplePie_IRI` calling all the functions using a static cache, with a parameter of `true` in $clear_cache, will work:

```
/**
 * Clean up
 */
public function __destruct() {
    $this->set_iri(null, true);
    $this->set_path(null, true);
    $this->set_authority(null, true);
}
```

Which will now result in no gain in memory consumption over time:

[image: SimplePie fixed]

[**Git Issue**](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues/260)

Comment: How about a pull request to SimplePie?

Comment: And while you're at it, remove the static variable out of that function and move to the class so you don't need to introduce another optional parameter to a function this is unrelated to. You can make it a private static if you only want to be able to reset it from within class functions. +1 for finding out the cause.

Comment: Hi h2oooooo

Your solution seems to solve my problem when I'm using php 5.2.17. But if I use my server with 5.3.28 it seems to not work. Is this to be expected? (is there another solution for this issue?)

Thanks!