# Static function caches that aren't being cleaned in PHP 5.3.28?

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-leaks, simplepie

I'm using SimplePie with PHP 5.2.17 to parse my RSS feeds through the WordPress plugin [feedwordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/feedwordpress/). This works well and without problems if I make sure to use [this patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337179/why-am-i-getting-memory-leaks-in-simplepie-when-using-item-get-permalink) to simplepie (in the file IRI.php).

However, if I change my PHP to use version 5.3.28 - the memory leak (or some other memory leak) starts and my site crashes. Any idea what might be causing it / how to solve it?

(or in other words, is there a reason [this patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337179/why-am-i-getting-memory-leaks-in-simplepie-when-using-item-get-permalink) should work in 5.2 and not in PHP 5.3?)

Thanks.

Comment: patch looks clean to me, what error log says about your crash?

Comment: Thanks Gowri. I use a managed VPS so I don't have access to all of the logs. Which error logs should I ask for? (I checked in the FTP and there was no error_logs file that seemed relevant)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP 5.3 isn't fully backward compatible with PHP 5.2,

In your case, the use of the `clearstatcache()` is probably the cause of the memory leak.

As you can see in the [Migrating from PHP 5.2.x to PHP 5.3.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) document:

> clearstatcache() no longer clears the realpath cache by default.

This issue can be fixed by [explicitly](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) setting the `$clear_realpath_cache` parameter to `true`

```
clearstatcache(true)
```

Comment: That is very interesting Uri! Where should I include that code? (in IRI.php ? in the beginning of it/ or somewhere else?)

Comment: @TalGalili I'd suggest including it directly on SimplePie source code. ☺

(I was thinking about linking to their source code from here, than I found your recent activity on their Github issues…)

Comment: @TomerCohen - I'd be happy to. But where should it go?

Comment: Adding this line to the destructor at `SimplePie_IRI` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Uri. 
Just to be sure, you mean to add it to the beginning of "__destruct() "?
And would it be PHP 5.2 compatible?

Comment: I'd put it at the end of the the `__destruct()` function, PHP 5.2 clears the realpath cache by default, so it should have no effect